# In what order is an enumerator's methods called?

Tags: c#, linked-list, enumerator

I want to know because I am planning on using an enumerator for a linked list and want to be able to remove a node if its data is changed to a certain value during the programs running. But since an enumerator would have its MoveNext() get the next node in the list I want to know if the MoveNext() is called after the Current's get.

In otherwords, will this work without the linked list enumerator stopping right after the remove.

```
foreach (Node<Object> it in myLinkedList)
{
    if (it.data().isGone())
    {
        myLinkedList.remove(it);
    }
}

public boolean remove(Node<E> node)
{
    node.setData(node.next().data());
    node.setNext(node.next().next());
}
```

Comment: The contract for `IEnumerator` specifically requires that you do *not* do what you are planning to do. It is always wrong to modify a collection while you are enumerating over it. If you do, then you should abandon the enumeration.

Comment: I'm new to trying out enumerators in c#, I still don't know if mine is correct or working.

Comment: @EricLippert **Edit: modifying a collection while enumerating its elements is a bad idea.** That said, there is no requirement that the enumerator be operating on the same view of the data that is modified by the `Remove` method. For example, most of the collections in `System.Collections.Concurrent` implement `GetEnumerator()` by creating and enumerating a point-in-time snapshot of the underlying collection, so modifications while enumerating are allowed.

Comment: @user2375782: If you are defining your own linked list class then make a method with signature `void Remove(Func<E, bool> predicate)` that safely modifies the list to remove all items that match the predicate. That's what `List<T>` does.

Comment: Sorry, I just figured as soon as they tried it with LinkedList, the exception would be thrown immediately and answer their own question. Didn't think that they were implementing their own linked list (which is obvious now from a second reading). Note to self: don't browse SO when tipsy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation for `IEnumerator<T>`, the `MoveNext()` method will throw an `InvalidOperationException` if the collection is modified after the enumerator was created.

[`IEnumerator<T>.MoveNext()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.movenext.aspx)

Even if you implement your own enumerator that does not behave this way (including a select few included in .NET), you should never modify a collection inside of a `foreach` statement which is enumerating the elements of that collection, since that is an immediate visual indication that your code is likely to throw an exception.